# How to get location immediately after user grant the permission on iOS?

Tags: ios

I'm currently calling `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` to ask for location permission. Is there a way to get coords from device right after user grant the permission? I have `didUpdateToLocation` but it's not being called right away.

Comment: As you didn't show any code, it's impossible to say what you're doing wrong, if anything. But you might not be; getting location takes time, as the sensors have to warm up and the GPS has to obtain a fix. In any case, if you just want the location, once, then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65819132/how-to-copy-user-location-only-once-from-location-manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `didUpdateLocations` not `didUpdateToLocation`